# Criar um botao de mudar o preço

Tags: javascript, html

Como eu faço para criar um botao, que ao clicar "pp" apareça o valor "r$70,00" e "p" apareça "r$100,00", "M" "r$150,00" e "G" "r$180,00"

Quero usar o html e o js, 
Olhem como ta agora,

```
<select style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" name="service" required class="border-box-contact">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
            <option value = 1>PP (~1,2kg)</option>
            <option value = 2>P (~1,8kg)</option>
            <option value = 3>M (~2,5kg)</option>
            <option value = 4>G (~3,5kg)</option>

            <script>
                if( value = 1){
                    return "Preço: R$ 70,00"
                }else if (value = 2){
                    return "Preço: R$ 100,00"
                }else if (value = 3){
                    return "Preço: 150,00"
                }else if (value = 4){
                    return "Preço: 180,00"
                }
            </script>
```

Nao estou conseguindo fzr funfar, alguem me help?

Comment: No caso a alteração vai ser nesse proprio selec ai teriam 3 botões que ao clicar ele mudaria o valor desse select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que precisa, mas fiz uso do jQuery com algumas funções, [`.change();`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) para que ao trocar o valor  do **select** ela seja executada. a [`.text();`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text) par atualizar o span em questão com o valor;

```js
$("#service").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  if (value == 1) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 70,00");
  } else if (value == 2) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 100,00");
  } else if (value == 3) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 150,00");
  } else if (value == 4) {
    $("#valor").text("Preço: R$ 180,00");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="service" style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" name="service" required class="border-box-contact">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value=1>PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value=2>P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value=3>M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value=4>G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>
<span id="valor" class="valor"></span>
```

Teste e veja se é isso que precisa.

Comment: Em vêz de `var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();` basta `var value = this.value`;

Comment: @Sergio carca que maneiro, a forma que tu fez ficou significativamente mais pratica.

Comment: Mt bom, incrivel!

Answer (score 2):

Cria um objeto com esses valores e depois escuta escolhas no `select` com `.addEventListener('change', function() {`. Assim podes saber o preço ligado a cada opção...

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const precos = {
  1: '70,00',
  2: '100, 00',
  3: '150,00',
  4: '180,00'
};

const produtos = document.querySelector('select[name="service"]');
const mostradoPreco = document.querySelector('#preco span');

produtos.addEventListener('change', function() {
  mostradoPreco.textContent = precos[this.value];
});
```

```html
<select style="margin: 0 5% 0 13%;" name="service" required class="border-box-contact">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Tamanho</option>
  <option value=1>PP (~1,2kg)</option>
  <option value=2>P (~1,8kg)</option>
  <option value=3>M (~2,5kg)</option>
  <option value=4>G (~3,5kg)</option>
</select>

<p id="preco">Preço: R$ <span></span></p>
```